# Add facebook like button within session

Tags: facebook, session, colorbox

I'm currently having the following code in a colorbox iframe:

```
 <? If($_Session['login']) { ?>

 Complete website + Metaheaders facebook like button + fb like button

 <? } else { header('location: index.php'); ?>
```

So if someone has logged in, a session is set and he can view the colorbox content. If no session is set, you will be redirected to the main page.

My problem is the following: when someone is logged in and pushing the fb like button in the colorbox iframe, he grabs the data of index.php. When I remove the if session check statement, he grabs the right data, so from the metaheaders within the colorbox iframe. How can I use a fb like button within a php session

Comment: try insert your url within [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check your meta tags and such.
Else I am a bit confused with the question

Comment: The facebook debugger gives me the content of index.php... While the session is true...